# Inserting a dictionary of tuples into a table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to insert a dictionary who's key's correspond to a column in a 
Postgres database, and whose values (the values are tuples) should be inserted into the rows for that column in the table.

Here is my code, along with the Postgres table:

```
samples_data_dict  = {'replicate_group_id': replicate_group_id_values_tuple, 
                          'sample_id': sample_id_values_tuple,
                          'chip_type': chip_type_values_tuple,
                          'dataset_id': dataset_id_values_tuple}

    for k, v in samples_data_dict.items():

        # insert_statement = 'insert into samples (%s) values %s'
        # cursor.execute(insert_statement, (eval(k), tuple(v)))
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO samples (%s) VALUES (%s);", (eval(k), v))
        conn.commit()
```

---

Postgres table record, with \x on formatting:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------+--
id                       | 1
sample_id                | 1
chip_type                | 
dataset_id               | 
sample_name_long         | 
sample_name              | 
replicate_group_id       | 
media                    | 
generic_sample_type      | 
sample_type              | 
cell_line                | 
facs_profile             | 
reprogramming_method     | 
tissue_organism_part     | 
sample_description       | 
age                      | 
final_cell_type          | 
sex                      | 
organism                 | 
developmental_stage      | 
labelling                | 
genetic_modification     | 
parental_cell_type       | 
sample_type_long         |
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transformer.py", line 172, in <module>
    main()
  File "transformer.py", line 141, in main
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO samples (%s) VALUES (%s);", (eval(k), v))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'replicate_group_id' is not defined
```

I am using 'eval(k)' to get the value of the keys in the dictionary without the quotation marks '', otherwise I receive a syntax error from Postgres. But removing the quotation marks (I think) means that the key is not recognized in my dictionary anymore. How can I get around this?

Comment: So, the values are tuples, not just one item?  How many rows are you expecting to have at the end?  Do all of the values tuples have the same number of items?

Comment: Yes, all values are tuples with quite a lot of rows each (1000's). All of the values have different numbers of items. These tuples have been created from a data frame, constructed from a .tsv file.

Comment: So will each row only have id and one other column be non-null?  The one record you show only has one value, so are you also planning on iterating over each value in the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

I created that record manually as an example of the column layout. I want to iterate over each tuple and insert each value into a record with its corresponding column. For example:

Dict = {Column: (val1,val2,val3)}

For values in the dict tuples:
     Insert values where column matches column

Intended result:

Record1
Column:val1

Record2
Column:val2

Record 3
Column:val3